# Expo Face Detector not providing settings objects

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set up a face detector on expo.

First I import the package and set up the state hook:

```
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import * as FaceDetector from "expo-face-detector";
const [faces, setFaces] = useState([]);
```

And set up the `onFacesDetected` function:

```
const onFacesDetected = async ({ faces }) => {
    setFaces(faces);
    console.log({ faces });
  };
```

And finally the camera:

```
<Camera
          style={styles.camera}
          ratio={"2:1"}
          ref={(r) => {
            camera = r;
          }}
          onFacesDetected={onFacesDetected}
          faceDetectorSettings={{
            mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.fast,
            detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.none,
            runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.all,
            minDetectionInterval: 125,
            tracking: false,
          }}
        >
```

But I am getting an error that the package doesnt provide the object needed (as in the docs tutorial):

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'FaceDetector.Constants.Mode')]

I have tried reinstalling the package to no avail.

Any help on how to troubleshoot this is appreciated..

**EDIT:** in VSCode I see that `Constants` is not defined by hovering it. It shows this error:

> Property 'Constants' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/david/Projects/adshare/node_modules/expo-face-detector/build/FaceDetector")'.
> `

Answer (score 1):

After looking in `node_modules/expo-face-detector/` I was able to see that the functions were renamed in the latest version, but the docs have not been updated anywhere.

It is now:

```
faceDetectorSettings={{
    mode: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorMode.fast, 
    detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorLandmarks.none,
    runClassifications: FaceDetector.FaceDetectorClassifications.all,
    minDetectionInterval: 125,
    tracking: false,
    }}
```